# Improving module structure

Tags: ruby, thread-safety, refactoring

I created small API library, everything worked fine, until I realized, that I need multiple configurations.

It looks like this:

```
module Store
  class Api
    class << self
      attr_accessor :configuration

      def configure
        self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
        yield configuration
      end

      def get options = {}
        url = "#{configuration.domain}/#{options[:resource]}"
        # ResClient url ...
      end
    end
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :domain

    def initialize options = {}
      @domain = options[:domain]
    end
  end

  class Product
    def self.get
      sleep 5
      Api.get resource: 'products'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it simultaneously, it override module configuration.

```
Thread.new do
  10.times do 
    Store::Api.configure do |c|
      c.domain = "apple2.com"
    end
    p Store::Product.get
  end
end

10.times do 
  Store::Api.configure do |c|
    c.domain = "apple.com"
  end
  p Store::Product.get
end
```

I can't figure out, how make this module better. Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't want multiple threads to compete for one resource, you shouldn't have made it a singleton. Try moving object configuration from class to its instances, then instantiate and configure them separately.

There is more to refactor here, but this solves your problem:

```
module Store
  class API
    attr_reader :domain

    def initialize(options = {})
      @domain = options[:domain]
    end

    def products
      sleep 5
      get resource: 'products'
    end

    private

    def get(options = {})
      url = "#{configuration.domain}/#{options[:resource]}"
      # ResClient url ...
    end
  end
end

Thread.new do
  10.times do 
    api = Store::API.new(domain: 'apple2.com')
    p api.products
  end
end

10.times do 
  api = Store::API.new(domain: 'apple.com')
  p api.products
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. May I "share" this api variable somehow? Or it needs to be send like param over and over?

Comment: @JiriKolarik There are several ways to do that. If you just don't want to pass an `API` reference into parameters, you can invert dependencies and get products right from your API. Moreover, since it's better to use immutable objects over multiple threads anyway, you don't need a complicated configuration for your API and can configure it at initialization. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant simplify api this much. I have much more models with more methods, not only get products, plus some classes to resolve URL and so on. That's the reason, why I created separated class Product in my example

Comment: @JiriKolarik It is actually good that you created a separate class. This way you can separate responsibilities between classes. The thing is about how you manage your dependencies and what classes can produce other classes. I can't recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Object-Oriented-Design-Ruby-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321721330) highly enough.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation, I'll give a shot